# How can I Add Friends in my QuickBlox Chat in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, chat, quickblox

I searched the quickblox documents but couldn't find API to add users/friends to my chat account. I am building an app which requires user to have their own personal chat account. Also, I need to retrieve those user's current location. Please help!

Comment: you can manage by webservice.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel By webservice, but how exactly in steps, like I need to ask my backend developer to make exact API's for the same. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want retrive current location of user :
 ask your developer to add additional parameter 
1)Latitude 
2)Longitude

you can get user's current location by CLLocationManager

now in registrartion webservice add this parameter

you can retrive user's currentlocation

Comment: ok @Krutarth, also I need to add friends to my quickblox account, like on sign up when I call "retrieve all users" quickblox api, there should be no users and henceforth add friends with particular username or email id to my account. Need to know how to add users in my quickblox account from 0 friends to up.

Comment: you can manage add  friend or remove friend by using webservice.

Comment: guys, to add friends simply we need to manage it by web service as answered by @Krutarth. Thanks for answering.